# Requiero que el resultado este en un text o label en lugar de un alert

Tags: javascript, alert

Tengo esta estructura para realizar una suma de un producto con características, sin embargo, me gustaría que en lugar de un alert, mostrara el resultado ya sea en un label o en un input text, me pueden dar una mano por favor.

Por su ayuda, gracias.

```js
function pluss ()
{
var Number1=parseInt(document.getElementById('Num1').value);
var Number2=parseInt(document.getElementById('Num2').value);
var Number3=parseInt(document.getElementById('Num3').value);
var Number4=parseInt(document.getElementById('Num4').value);
var ResultL;
var ResultSh;
var ResultH;
var Total;
ResultL = Number1 * Number2 ;
ResultsH = Number3 * Number4;
ResultH = ResultsH * Number1;
Total = ResultH + ResultL

alert ("resultado = "+ Total);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenemos el label objetivo en nuestro HTML

```
<label id="total"></label>
```

---

Con `JavaScript` puedes acceder a elementos del [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Referencia_DOM_de_Gecko/Introducci%C3%B3n) de distintas maneras; en este caso nos basta con el método `getElementById()`, el cual obtiene el elemento mediante su atributo `id`

```
function pluss ()
{
  // ...
  Total = ResultH + ResultL;
  
  // Obtenemos la referencia del label donde vamos a imprimir el resultado
  var label = document.getElementById('total');
  // Accedemos a su text para plasmar lo que necesitamos.
  label.innerText = Total;
}
```

Comment: Daniel, muchisimas gracias mi estimado, funciono perfectamente, te lo agradezco mucho.